# Stop Hangouts sending message when enter is pressed

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 and installed Hangouts (version 2.0.122) recently.  It is a great tool to organize all my messages together. However, it is quite annoying that it sends messages when I accidentally press enter, causing me to send unfinished messages.  Also I don't know how to insert a new line.  I looked into the settings but could not find any relevant options.

The iphone version treats enter as inserting new line so it does not have this problem.

Thanks for any tips you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change this. In Android, the app can tell the keyboard (or *input method*) what extra *actions* to show (such as Send). The app can also specify that the text field can only hold single-line text, as in this case.

What you could do is switch to a different keyboard app. You might be able to find one that puts the action in a different place (not in place of the enter key) that's harder to press by accident, or that completely ignores the action that's hinted by the app.

Answer (score 2):

I heard someone who used Swift keyboard and it apparently solved this specific problem, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Could you please link the app here?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download another keyboard from the Play-store,
the personalized keyboard will override the one with no enter-key.

I downloaded one called [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey), 
but this is not the only-one, any other keyboard should also work.

Comment: I don't think the OP wanted to get rid of the "enter" key (which might be very much needed in other places). Question was how to change the behavior or the Hangouts app.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest available way is to get 'Enter' by holding the Shift Key.
If your a gesture typing user,just drag from 'Shift to Enter' key for entering into the new Line.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It would be enough, Probably, to just go to Settings, ‘Language & input’ and to the specific submenu for each keyboard, Android or Swiftkey, we’ll find all the options, for "Text correction” and “Typing & Autocorrect” respectively.

Comment: What has this to do with sending messages when enter is pressed?